# How to find upper and lower bounds of a given set?

Tags: calculus

I'm taking Calculus 1 and we are studying sequences. They ask us to find upper and lower bounds and sometimes the supremum and infimum of them. I can usually find them by intuition, but I want something more rigorous and, if it's possible, a systematic approach.

Thank you!

Comment: It's hard to come up with a systematic approach. For $n\in\mathbb N$, let $a_n$ be the smallest number $k$ such that $2n+2$ can be written as sum of $k$ primes. Then certainly $\inf a_n = 2$. But how could one determine $\sup a_n$?

Answer (score 0):

First, some definitions: If $U$ is the set of upper bounds, then for all $u\in U, n \in \Bbb{N}:x_n \leq u$. To prove some prospective $u$  is an upper bound, you have to prove that no $x_n$ is greater than $u$.

And then $\inf(U)$ is the lowest value of $u \in U$, which means that it is the lowest possible value that you could correctly say was an upper bound on $x_n$.

Sometimes $\inf(U)$ is one of the $x_n$, but in the problems you are likely to be given, usually it will be some value that never is exactly equal to one of the $x_n$.  A simple example is the sequence $x_n = 1 - 2^{-n}$.  Since $2^{-n}$ is always positive, any number $u \geq 1$ will be an upper bound. And it is easy to see that $\inf(U)=1$.  By the way, that is often called the *least upper bound*.

The situation is similar for lower bounds/ sup,/ greatest lower bound.

A "systematic" approach to find some upper bound is to look at the expression for $x_n$ and break it into some terms which might be positive or negative, plus some terms which are always non-positive. Then if you replace the non-positive terms by zero, you get a value which is always greater than $x_n$, but that might still depend on $n$.  But if your breakup contained no $n$-dependent terms among the terms than might be positive or negative, then the sum of those terms will be an upper bound.

For example:  Let $x_n = \frac{\sin(n)}{n}$.  This is brooken up as follows:
$$x_n = \frac{\sin(n)}{n} = \frac{\sin(n)-1}{n} +\frac{1}{n} = \frac{\sin(n)-1}{n} + \frac{1-n}{n} +1 
$$
The first two of those terms are non-positive; the third does not depend on $n$, so an upper bound is $1$ (this happens not to be the least upper bound).

Answer (score 0):

When you are asked to find an upper bound of a given set, or a Lipschitz constant for some function, or a $\delta>0$ such that $\ldots$, and others like that then such a task doesn't have a unique answer: Any number satisfying certain conditions depending on the case will be accepted.

Therefore, presented with a sequence, as
$$x_n:={7+2\cos n\over 5-e^{-n}}\qquad(n\geq1)\ ,$$
use your intuition and experience to guess a possible upper bound $b$. You now have to sell this bound $b$ to your customer (or TA), which means: *You have to prove rigorously* that
$$x_n\leq b\qquad\forall n\geq1\ .$$
In the above example it should not be too difficult to prove that $b:={9\over2}$ is an upper bound for the given sequence.

It is another matter to find the *optimal*, or: *smallest* upper bound of the above sequence, which is denoted by $\sup_{n\geq1} x_n$. In order to prove that something converges, is Lipschitz-continuous, or just continuous, you don't need such optimal bounds, but when deriving really hard results you can't do without them.